# Using singleton HttpClient with Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient - getting System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient

I am trying to rework my Azure API client to use singleton `HttpClient` for `ServiceClient<T>`, since multiple sources suggested to do that (for performance, and it is also suggested approach for `HttpClient` which is used behind the scenes for `Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient` "in general")

I am using Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.2.3.12 version

I see that Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient has constructor for reusing `HttpClient`

```
protected ServiceClient(HttpClient httpClient, bool disposeHttpClient = true);
```

This is constructor for my API client in order to **reuse** HttpClient, but when it is called it fails with `System.MissingMethodException`: *Void Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, Boolean)*

```
public MyAPIclient(ServiceClientCredentials credentials, HttpClient client) 
    : base(client, disposeHttpClient: false)
{
    this._baseUri = new Uri("https://...");
    if (credentials == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("credentials");
    }
    this.Credentials = credentials;
    Credentials?.InitializeServiceClient(this);
}
```

This is how I call API client

```
using (var apiClient = new MyAPIclient(credentials, HttpClientSingleton.Client)) 
//I get Method not found 'Void Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, Boolean)'
{
    //some api call
}
```

This is how I instantiate my http client singleton

```
public static class HttpClientSingleton
{
    public static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) };
}
```

**Why do I get this exception** (I can see that `ServiceClient` **has** `ctor(httpClient, bool)`)?

**How to fix** this problem?

Comment: version of `HttpClient` ?

Comment: try restoring the nuget packages

Comment: @MatrixTai Assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0 ...NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll

Comment: Maybe you should try to update a new version, or changing the binding assembly, see this https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2857#issuecomment-422520170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Nkosi said, you should try restoring the nuget packages, clearing your obj/bin and rebuilding.  This usually happens when things get out of step.  With all the shadow caching etc etc things can end up mismatched.  I created a small example based on your code and there weren't any issues with it.  If you find that still doesn't work you should include more info on your file, like the class declarations and your using statements, and what version of .net you are using.

The below works for me for 4.5.2 ServiceClient 2.3.12

```
using Microsoft.Rest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var apiClient = new MyAPIclient(null, HttpClientSingleton.Client))
        //I get Method not found 'Void Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, Boolean)'
        {
            var httpClient = apiClient.HttpClient;
        }
    }

    public class MyAPIclient : ServiceClient<MyAPIclient>
    {
        protected Uri _baseUri { get; set; }
        protected ServiceClientCredentials Credentials { get; set; }

        public MyAPIclient(ServiceClientCredentials credentials, HttpClient client) : base(client, disposeHttpClient: false)
        {
            this._baseUri = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com");
            this.Credentials = credentials;
            if(credentials != null)
                Credentials?.InitializeServiceClient(this);
        }
    }

    public static class HttpClientSingleton
    {
        public static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) };
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hmm… did all this stuff, but still same outcome. I had one idea that probably I not instantiating HttpClient correctly (see in post)? I am using .NET 4.5.2 and exception is thrown when i try to construct Api client `Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, Boolean)'.`

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new, but that code I copy/pasted above works with .net 4.5.2 and ServiceClient 2.3.12.  Do you have mismatched nuget packages maybe across multiple projects and maybe you are getting the wrong one?

Comment: How can I check if I have mismatched nuget packages? How to ensure that specific package is used? Is it with app.config/web.config file with setting bindingRedirect for dependentAssembly?

Comment: Sometimes you get a warning in the build output, but if you right click on the solution file in VS, you have the option to “Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...” and if you find the package you can see what projects have which version installed.  Generally it’s easier to manage packages through that interface than doing them individually.

Comment: I created a clean Console project and used my ApiClient from that solution and it was working... so I guess you are right - I'll see if I can find problem with my original solution and accept your answer then. Thanks!

Comment: Turned out that I had multiple Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient packages installed… upgraded all to 2.3.12 and after that problem was solved.