# Periodically reload credentials on SearchServiceClient and child ISearchIndexClient singletons

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

In our web app dependency injection, we configure the `ISearchIndexClient` instances returned by .NET Azure Search SDK's `SearchServiceClient.Indexes.GetClient(...)` as a singletons.

We did this because of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43502662 mentions that these classes share a single HTTP client. To avoid port exhaustion we want a single shared `HttpClient`.

The problem with this, however, is that this means we need to restart the web app to cause the new query key (secret) to be reloaded from KeyVault. Consider a secret rotation flow: we need to restart/redeploy our web app after putting the new secret in KeyVault but before invalidating the old secret.

Is there a factory or another pattern the Azure Search .NET SDK recommends for periodically getting a new `SearchServiceClient` or `ISearchIndexClient`? I want a singleton most of the time for performance reasons but would like a new instance every couple of hours (for example).

Our code looks something like this right now. It uses Autofac but I think it gets the point across:

```
containerBuilder
    .Register(c =>
    {
        var options = c.Resolve<IOptionsSnapshot<AzureSearchConfiguration>>();
        return new SearchServiceClient(
            options.Value.SearchServiceName,
            new SearchCredentials(options.Value.SearchServiceApiKey));
    });

containerBuilder
    .Register(c =>
    {
        var serviceClient = c.Resolve<SearchServiceClient>();
        var options = c.Resolve<IOptionsSnapshot<AzureSearchConfiguration>>();
        return serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(options.Value.SearchIndexName);
    })
    .SingleInstance();
```

I can build a time-based factory that spits out a new `SearchServiceClient` or `ISearchIndexClient` from time to time but I was hoping that something already existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing your own factory/pool for `SearchIndexClient` instances is the way to go. Unfortunately this kind of functionality isn't included in the SDK, so you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Understood. It's not my favorite answer, but if that's the way it has to be then we will look into implementing a factor in the future. For now, we'll just redeploy the web app after secret rotation.

Comment: Eventually we plan to support MSI and AAD so you won't have to rotate your own secrets at all. No timeline yet though.