# Azure Search .NET SDK: SearchIndexClient & Dependency Injection

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

What's the recommended way to register a SearchIndexClient into DI container? (let's say we only have a single index)
Register it as singleton or transient?

Answer (score 2):

In an **ASP.NET Core** app, you can inject the client as follows.

Install the packages: [Microsoft.Extensions.Azure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/), [Azure.Search.Documents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Search.Documents) (this is the latest)

In the `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`, register the client:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddSearchIndexClient(new 
            Uri("my resource url"), new 
            AzureKeyCredential("my resource key"));
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Now say you want to use the client in your controller, you can inject it like so:

```cs
public class MyApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SearchIndexClient _searchIndexClient;
  
    public MyApiController(SearchIndexClient searchIndexClient)
    {
        _searchIndexClient = searchIndexClient;
    }

}
```

You may not want to put your credentials directly in `ConfigureServices` though, in which case you could store them in `appsettings.Development.json` (or `appsettings.Production.json`):

```json
  "SearchDocument": {
    "endpoint": "my resource url",
    "credential": { "key": "my resource key" }
  }
```

and do this in `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{   
    builder.AddSearchIndexClient(
        Configuration.GetSection("SearchDocument")); 
});
```

Read more about [Dependency injection with the Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should register it as a singleton, as long as you make sure to avoid using properties and methods that aren't thread-safe. Most of them are thread-safe; just avoid setting mutable properties from multiple threads and you should be fine.

For a more in-depth discussion of why this is the recommended practice and how you can extend it for more complex scenarios, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769937/implications-of-using-azuresearch-sdk-with-static-dictionary-of-30-40-isearchind).