# How to achieve the best and less query execution time using Azure Function Query App (C#) from Azure Search

Tags: c#, design-patterns, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search

I am using **Azure Functions** to query data from the **Azure Search (Multi-Indexes for Multi-Countries)**. Currently, I am simply creating an object of **SearchIndexClient** inside the **using statement** by passing QueryKey, ServiceName and IndexName and querying data from Azure Search. Thus for each request, an object of **SearchIndexClient** is created, query execution happened and then object disposed. 
Is it the right approach from performance point of view?

If not, then what improvements/best practices can i use in the application to increase the performance on the production environment. Do i need to use any design pattern for object creation?

I observed that currently query execution takes more time than object creation.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to re-use `SearchIndexClient` instances where possible. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769937/implications-of-using-azuresearch-sdk-with-static-dictionary-of-30-40-isearchind) for details. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in an Azure Function.

Even if creating the client is a relatively small part of your end-to-end latency, you should still avoid creating too many of them at once. Each client creates an `HttpClient` under the hood. Creating too many HTTP clients can exhaust the TCP connection pool, so the scalability of your app might suffer.

For a broader discussion of performance issues, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-performance-optimization).

Comment: Thanks. I will check on these links